# Magento2 - How to catch error when id doesn't exist loading product with '\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product'

Tags: magento2, error

I am adding a product to the cart using \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product and works fine if the product id exist.

```
public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        ...
)
{
        ...
        $this->_product = $product;
        ...
}
    try{
        $product = $this->_product->load($productID);
    }catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
        $response = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
        $response->setData(['message' => 'Subscription id not founded']);
        $response->setHttpResponseCode(406);
        return $response;
    }
```

but I get an exemption when the id don't exist:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The product wasn't found. Verify the product and try again.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The product wasn't found. Verify the product and try again.
<pre>#1 Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart->addProduct(&Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#000000001b3988ae0000000074f86046#, array('product' => 1, 'qty' => 1)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#2 Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\Interceptor->___callParent('addProduct', array(&Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Interceptor#000000001b3988ae0000000074f86046#, array('product' => 1, 'qty' => 1))) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
```

How can I avoid the code to brake. I tried try and catch or `if(this->_product->load($productID);))` But nothing working.

Thanks

Comment: i think you try this may be help you : try {
    $product = $this->_product->load($productID);
} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e){
    $product = false;
}

Comment: @MohitPatel It never moves to the next line the error it is at the $product = $this->_product->load($productID); and the catch never get it.

Comment: where is `$productID` in your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $this->_product->load($notExistentIdProduct); doesn't produce an exception.

The issue was trying to validate the result of the method load using the instance of the variable without checking an attribute.

Instead of:

```
$product = $this->_product->load($productID);
if (!$product) {
      ...
}
```

Should be:

```
$product = $this->_product->load($productID);
if (!$product->getId()) {
      ...
}
```

Comment: If $product is null or false for whatever reason that could throw an error. Protect that further `if ($product && $product->getId()) { // product loaded

Comment: I tested and it is all validation needed, even if $productID has a string or an invalid number.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

https://github.com/DominicWatts/OrderHistory/blob/4046ba20767778c1ab4ffa73d812e54814b4451b/Controller/Sales/Reorder.php#L115-L136

```
            try {
                $add = $this->productFactory->create()->load($product->getId());
                if (!$add) {
                    $this->messageManager->addWarnng(
                        __('Cannot add %1 x %2 at this time', $qty, $add->getName())
                    );
                    continue;
                }
                $productName = $product->getName();
                $this->cart->addProduct(
                    $add,
                    $qty
                );
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(
                    __('Added %1 x %2', $qty, $add->getName())
                );
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException(
                    $e,
                    __("%1 %2", $product->getName(), $e->getMessage())
                );
            }
```

Comment: Changing to \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory dosn't solve the problem.  I found that the issue is that the object doesn't get an error or a not validation in the !($add) so i just fixed adding !($product.getId())

Comment: could you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313388/magento-2-website-crash-always